# Cannot create list in iTextSharp that contains linebreaks

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to create an unordered list in C# using iTextSharp. Here is my code:

```
phrase.Clear();

iTextSharp.text.List list = new iTextSharp.text.List(List.UNORDERED, 10f);
list.SetListSymbol("\u2022");
list.IndentationLeft = 15f;
iTextSharp.text.ListItem listitem = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem("One");
listitem.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
list.Add(listitem);

listitem = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem("Two");
listitem.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
list.Add(listitem);

listitem = new iTextSharp.text.ListItem("Three");
listitem.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
list.Add(listitem);

phrase.Add(list);
```

Output I expect to see:

- One
- Two
- Three

Output I actually see:

OneTwoThree

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue with iTextSharp 5.5.13.2. Could you please share more code?

Comment: Can you share your output pdf and a minimal reproducible example?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example